# Making Wagtail user password optional not required

Tags: wagtail

When adding a new user we now have to add a password, before it was not mandatory. As we use CAS for login we don't need to set/store password for users. Is there anyway to make the user password optional again, apart from making a custom user model.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should be possible to do this as follows (based on the instructions in http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_user_models.html and the default form implementation at https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailusers/forms.py) :

In some_app/forms.py:

```
   from wagtail.wagtailusers.forms import UserCreationForm

   class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
       password_required = False
```

In settings/base.py:

```
   WAGTAIL_USER_CREATION_FORM = 'some_app.forms.CustomUserCreationForm'
```

The ability to create a user without a password was accidental, and was "fixed" in https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/3007 - however, since there is clearly a valid use case for this, we'll look into adding a more official/robust way of making password optional or removing it from the form.

Comment: This is now implemented and will be part of Wagtail 1.12. There are two new settings: WAGTAILUSERS_PASSWORD_REQUIRED (which can be set to false to make password optional) and WAGTAILUSERS_PASSWORD_ENABLED (which can be set to false to remove the field completely).